# Boolean 'not' in Python exception catching

Tags: python, exception

I try to construct a `except` clause that catches everything except [sic] a particular type of exception:

```
try:
    try:
        asdjaslk
    except not NameError as ne: #I want this block to catch everything except NameError
        print("!NameError- {0}: {1}".format(ne.__class__, ne))
except Exception as e: #NameError is the only one that should get here
    print("Exception- {0}: {1}".format(e.__class__, e))
```

The language accepts the `not` in the `except` clause, but does nothing with it:

```
>>> Exception- <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'asdjaslk' is not defined
```

Is it possible to do this or should I re`raise` them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to re-raise. An `except` statement can only whitelist, not blacklist.

```
try:
    asdjaslk
except Exception as ne:
    if isinstance(ne, NameError):
        raise
```

The `not NameError` expression returns `False`, so you are essentially trying to catch:

```
except False:
```

but no exception will ever match a boolean instance.

The syntax allows for any valid Python expression, and the thrown exception is matched against the outcome of that expression. `except SomeException if debug else SomeOtherException:` is perfectly valid, for example.

Comment: or `except NameError as ne: raise`

Comment: Should python accept False as a condition to be thrown?

Comment: Mmm, still weird that the language def permits the not here.

Comment: @RickyA: It permits *any valid expression*. The result of which is matched against the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can can try this:

```
try:
    # your code raising exceptions

except NameError:
    # catch the exception you don't want to catch
    # but immediately raise it again:
    print("re-raising NameError- {0}: {1}".format(ne.__class__, ne))
    raise

except Exception as e:
    # handle all other exceptions here
    print("catching Exception- {0}: {1}".format(e.__class__, e))
    pass
```